# Grid view of images inside a ScrollView - React Native

Tags: react-native

So this week I have started on my first pet project to get hands on learning experience with RN. So far so good I think. But now I have hit a bit of a road block, so I was hoping someone would help me out. So I have got a View of images (coming from an api). I am able to place the images in a grid view like so:

[image]

But once I place this view in a Flatlist, the whole layout gets messed up. Looks like this:

[image]

I have tried playing around with flex but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated

Code can be found here:
UPDATED:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c565d8f9d7dfa65646b7a3a81bf6330f

Answer (score 6):

FlatList has a numColumns attribute. 
Try:

```
<FlatList style={styles.FlatlistStyles} data={this.state.moviesTrending}
  numColumns={4}
  renderItem={({item}) => this.renderMoviesTrending(item)}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
 />
```

and add width `style={{ width: 200 }}` or any appropriate width to the child element (rendered by the renderMoviesTrending function).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `contentContainerStyle` instead of just `style` and set some flex props for it to work. For example:

`justifyContent: 'flex-start'`

`flexDirection: 'column'`

Comment: yes I did but, I see no change. list stays in like the last image

Comment: that's because on line 52 you set he wrap style to the list container. 
**You have to set it on the list itself**

Comment: never mind I figured it out with scrollview -> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86596a926ff9d40494dd6e47c08ddb75  but thanks again for your help and time

Comment: I do encounter want small issue the scrollview is not scrolling, more like bouncing. If I use the flatlist as an option then its duplicate all movies 3 times